# How to evaluate the integral: $\int\ln x\;\sin^{-1} x\, \operatorname d\!x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can the following integral integrated by parts?
$$\int\ln x\;\sin^{-1} x\, \operatorname d\!x$$

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: @swapnanilsaha There should be an empty check mark next to answers to your questions. Clicking that will accept someones answer. Note that you can only accept one answer.

Comment: @Holdsworth88 : Thankyou very much.

Comment: "Can the following integral integrated by parts?" - repeated use of it, yes. To start you out: $u=\arcsin\,x$, $\mathrm dv=\log\,x\mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integration by parts formula

$$\int u(x)\underset{dv}{\underbrace{v^{\prime }(x)dx}}=u(x)v(x)-\int v(x)
\underset{du}{\underbrace{u^{\prime }(x)dx}}.$$

If we apply the [LIATE rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Liate_rule) to

$$\int \ln x\arcsin x\,dx,$$

we should choose

$$u =\ln x,\quad dv=\arcsin x\,dx.$$

Normally there is a choice of the terms $u,v'$ of the integrand $uv'$ that makes integration much easier. However in the present case the other possible choice $u=\arcsin x,v'=\ln x$ leads to integrals of  similar difficulties.

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int \ln x\arcsin x\,dx, \qquad \text{(}v =\int \arcsin x\,dx\quad \text{see evaluation below)} \\
 &=&\left( \ln x\right) \left( x\arcsin x+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right) -\int \frac{
1}{x}\left( x\arcsin x+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right) \,dx \\
&=&\left( \ln x\right) \left( x\arcsin x+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right) -\int \arcsin
x\,dx-\int \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx \\
&&\text{(see evaluation of the last integral below)} \\
 &=&\left( \ln x\right) \left( x\arcsin x+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right)  -\left( \sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin x\right)  \\
&&-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+1}+C.
\\
&=&\left( -1+\ln x\right) \left( x\arcsin x+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right)  
-\sqrt{
1-x^{2}} -\frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+1}+C.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

- Evaluation of $\int \arcsin x\,dx$ by substitution $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int \arcsin x\,dx &=&\int u\cos u\,du,\quad u=\arcsin x \\
  &=&\cos u+u\sin u \\
  &=&\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x\arcsin x+C.
  \end{eqnarray*}$$
- Evaluation of $\int \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx$ by substitution and
  partial fractions
  $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx &=&-\int \frac{u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}\,du,\qquad
  u=\sqrt{1-x^{2}} \\
  &=&u+\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( u-1\right) -\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( u+1\right)  \\
  &=&u+\frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{u-1}{u+1} \\
  &=&\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+1}+C.
  \end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Alternatively, $$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, with this split the integral becomes $$\int \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-\text{arctanh}\frac{1}{
\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}+C.$$

Answer (score 2):

Following J.M.'s hint, you may want to prove, again integrating by parts, that
$$\int\log x\,dx=x\log x-x+C\,\,,\,\,C=\,\,\text{a constant}$$and perhaps also to note that
$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Let  I =  ∫ ln x * sin−1 x dx,

= x(ln x - 1) * arcsin x - ∫ x(ln x - 1) * 1/√(1 – x^2) dx

= x(ln x - 1) * arcsin x - ∫(ln x - 1) * x / √(1 – x^2) dx

= x(ln x - 1) * arcsin x + (ln x - 1) * √(1 – x^2) – ∫ (1/x) * √(1 – x^2) dx

Call this last integral  I1.

Put u = x^2;  then du/dx = 2x

∴ I1 = ∫ (1/(2u)) * √(1 – u) * du/dx dx

Put  u = 1 – v^2, v ≥ 0;  so du/dv = -2v

∴ I1 = ½ ∫ 1/(1 – v^2) * (-2v^2) dv

v^2 / (v^2 – 1) = (v^2 – 1 + 1) / (v^2 – 1) = 1 + 1 / (v^2 – 1)

= 1 + ½ (1/(v – 1)  - 1/(v + 1))

So  I1  = v + ½ ln (A * (v – 1) / (v + 1)),  where  A is the arbitrary constant

```
= √(1 – u) + ½ ln (A * (√(1 – u) – 1) / (√(1 – u) + 1)),

= √(1 – x^2) + ½ ln (A * (√(1 – x^2) – 1) / (√(1 – x^2) + 1)),
```

Add this to the other parts, and you are done.

I at first thought it could not be done in elementary functions; but there we are!)